# How to reuse already exec query mongodb mongoose in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

is that posible to reuse already `exec` mongodb/mongoose query in nodejs?

for example i create query like this to check if user exist or not:

```
const inviter = await User.findOne({ _id: req.userData._id }).exec()
// there's bunch of code bellow here before update the user data
```

basically if i want to update the data, then i have to write the same code again and add update function like this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.userData._id }, { $push: { invited: recipient.value } }, { useFindAndModify: false })
```

is that posible to continue the first query and add short query to update based on result of the first query, for example like this:

```
inviter.update({ $push: { invited: recipient.value }).exec()
```

i know this code is not work..

Answer (score 0):

you can use this approach :

```
 User.findOne({ _id: req.userData._id }).exec((err, result) => {
            if(result)
            {
             result.invited =  recipient.value;
             result.save((err) => {
              if (err) // do something
             });
            }
           

        })
    }
```